# Can an Iframe load its contents at the server side rather than client side?

Tags: asp.net, html, iframe, server-side

I know that setting runat="server" and specifying an id for an iframe control, makes it accessible on the server side but what I need is that the iframe source contents get loaded at server side not client side.

Is it possible?

Why do I need it this way?

Currently my iframe source site is configured for ntlm authentication and sso which means it would read my windows credentials whereas I'd need it reads the credentials provided by the site which hosts that iframe.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

No that cannot be done. It is not the way things work. If you need to load content on the server side, you can use the [`WebRequest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.aspx) class. But I doubt that that is what you want. I think you need to rethink your application design.

Comment: Thanks. so is it possible to make a request using webrequest and set its result to the iframe at the server side?

Comment: @Dynamic. No, an iframe cannot use the result of a webrequest. But you can emit the html in a placeholder in the page. But it's not the right solution. The right solution would be to have your users authenticate correctly with the website that you are displaying inside the iframe.

Comment: thanks. the problem I have with authentication is that the source site of iframe does support ntlm and sso. the host site (which is sharepoint) does support ntlm without sso. so I'd need to pass the credentials of sharepoint to the iframe site which is not necessarily the same windows identity.

Answer (score 0):

No, setting the runat="server" attribute of the iframe tag will allow you to modify it's attributes on the server side but the source of the iframe will still be downloaded from the client.

Comment: how to set the innerHtml of the iframe without using src? e.g.  <iframe id="iframeWebchat" name="iframeWebchat" height="100%"
     width="100%" scrolling="0" frameborder="0">
     <html><body>hello</body></html>
     </iframe>

Comment: found it:  window['iframeId'].document.body.innerHTML =
             '<html><body>hello</body></html>';

Comment: I have used iframe in the Accordion Control and at the time of findcontrol how can i get this on server side?
Is it HtmlGenericControl?